# Autoplay once in HTML 5 and/or video.js

Tags: javascript, html, video.js

I want an embedded video (MP4) to autoplay once only in video.js then either return to a poster or the first frame so a click will commence play for a 2nd time.

Currently its autoplaying but stopping on the last frame and the only way i can re play is by dragging play bar to the left. (except in crome where it plays from the start with a click)

Comment: You need to include whatever code you have, or any try you might have made... otherwise it will be difficult to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can go back to the first frame.
suppose your video.js player object named "player":

```
player.on("ended", function () {
    this.currentTime(0); //move to start
}
```